# Chrome extension that blocks a class of elements in a specific website?

Tags: chrome

I have a chrome extension called uBlock, which allows me to right-click on an element of a website and press "block element", so that from then on, that element will be removed when you visit the website.

You can block elements by specifying some string such as

> "###vm-bJXJ183eBSY > .end.edit-expand-menu-button"

However, what I would like to do is not just block one element, but all elements off that type:

> "###vm-XXXX > .end.edit-expand-menu-button"

Where XXXX is ANY sequence of numbers and characters (both capital and lower case). That is, all such elements should be blocked.

Is there a chrome extension that allows you to do this?

(also, ideally, I'd like to be able to put a password on this chrome extension, so that such elements cannot be unblocked without the password, but this is secondary).

Comment: I presume your examples are CSS selectors. In them, do any of the pound signs indicate an ID selector, or do they represent numbers that are part of the class name?

Comment: @Kodiologist, I don't know. I don't know what a CSS selector is, or an ID selector, or what a pound sign does. How could I find out?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html is a good place to start. However, going by your prose description of what you want to do, CSS probably won't cut it; you'll need to write a little JavaScript.

Comment: @Kodiologist, How do I know whether uBlock will be able to do this in the first place?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not familiar with uBlock Origin's filter syntax.